# $_SERVER['http_referer'] vs .htaccess deny all allow 1

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-referer

I'm curious as to the difference of denying access using the global `$_server['http_referer']` and using **.htaccess** with `deny from all/allow from ip`

Are both bypassable in the same way or is **.htaccess** a secure way to stop access based on the referer?

Kind regards,

Comment: What is your ultimate goal that you are considering using these?

Comment: This would be used when a website directs to us with a querystring to symbolize a yes or no, by restricting to referers from only their websites ip we can stop people faking the querystring value? as only links generated by their website/code would pass the check, right?

Comment: See my updated answer to address this need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is easy to spoof so depending on that for anything non-trivial is not a good idea.

Using .htaccess with `deny from all/allow from ip` is better is better because it restricts access to a list of IPs you specify. But this starts to fail if you allow entire blocks access to your site. Then this can be defeated  easily by using a proxy.

So neither is going to be a perfect solution to keeping someone out of your website.

**update**

Based on your comment you should consider an authentication method that only the referring sites and you know about. Basically they should be passing you a hash that is created from secret values that change per request. That way they can't be spoofed and you can verify with certainty that the request is legitimate.

Comment: I think .htaccess will be better since it on apache level and not PHP. But, both can be bypass.

Comment: I am running zend and the area of our website I want restricted isn't a real directory but a route created in zend, is there a way to set a url to be affected by a rule in the .htaccess? or does .htaccess only effect those within its subdirectories?